# Extract paragraph (>800 chars) from text files

Tags: php, string, text

I need to extract rather long excerpts from text files. For this reason I decided to extract the first encountered paragraph, which is >800 characters long, and cut it to 800 chars, adding "..." in the end. If such paragraph is not found – then step down to 700, 600, 500.

Please help me to improve this PHP code.
Or, if you know the bash-solution – would be nice too. Thanks in advance.

```
if ($text != false && $text != '') {
    preg_match('#^(.{50,100})(\s+)#s', $text, $aSubject);
    preg_match('#([^\n]{400,800})(.*)#', $text, $aAnnotation);
    $text = preg_replace('#([\n\r\t\s]+)#s', " ", $text);
    // $text = preg_replace('#([\w|\s]+)#s', "\1", $text);
    $wordcount = count(explode(" ", $text));
    // if (isset($aAnnotation[1]) && isset($aSubject[1])) {
    if (isset($aAnnotation[1])) {
        $sAnnotation = preg_replace('#(\s{2,100})#', ' ', $aAnnotation[1]);
        $stmt = $hDB->prepare("INSERT INTO {$_S['tableText']} (filename, text) values (?, ?)");
        $stmt->execute([$aFilename[1], trim($text)]);
        // $stmt = $hDB->prepare("INSERT INTO {$_S['tableKeywords']} (filename, subject, annotation) values (?, ?, ?)");
        // $stmt->execute([$File, $aSubject[1], $sAnnotation]);
        $stmt = $hDB->prepare("INSERT INTO {$_S['tableKeywords']} (filename, annotation, wordcount) values (?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->execute([$aFilename[1], $sAnnotation, $wordcount]);
        $aExts[$aFilename[3]] = (isset($aExts[$aFilename[3]])) ? $aExts[$aFilename[3]] + 1 : 1;
        // unlink($_S['textDir'] . '/' . $File);
    }
}
```

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If it is less than `800` characters why do you need to cut it down? You also don't need a regex for this (as currently written), http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php.

Comment: Though your requirement is to get a bash script, the code you have posted is php. So it is not appropriate to tag bash in it.

Comment: Thank you, @Michael, I should post this in codereview.

Comment: @Chris85, I should explain more clearly. I meant not the first paragraph, but the first encountered paragraph, which meets the requirement: length>800 characters. If such paragraph is not found through the document – then search for >700, if not – then search for >600 ...

Comment: @sjsam, I just wanted to say, if the solution in bash is simpler – I'd be glad to hear it too. That's why #bash tag is pretty much applicable.